# Having trouble with an epsilon-delta limit proof of $\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\sqrt{6−x}−2}{\sqrt{3−x}−1}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove

> $$\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{\sqrt{6−x}−2}{\sqrt{3−x}−1}$$

I know the limit is 1/2, but I can't seem to manipulate the absolute value properly to get |x-2|*(something I can find an upper bound for), partially because simplifying then multiplying the top and bottom by the bottom conjugate gets |x-2| on the bottom

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax while posting anything here as it makes it easier to understand what's being said. Here's a quick reference link that you might find useful https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

You do a great job by multiplying the conjugate of the bottom

Hint: Do that again for the top one and it will make the expression much easier to handle.

Answer (score 1):

We have to show, $|\frac{\sqrt{6-x}-2}{\sqrt{3-x}-1} - \frac{1}{2}|< \epsilon$ whenever $|x - 2|<\delta(\epsilon)$.

$|\frac{\sqrt{6-x}-2}{\sqrt{3-x}-1} - \frac{1}{2}|=|\frac{\sqrt{3-x}+1}{\sqrt{6-x}+2} - \frac{1}{2}|$  $[\because x\ne 2]$ $= |\frac{2\sqrt{3-x} - \sqrt{6-x}}{2(\sqrt{6-x} + 2)}| = |\frac{3(2-x)}{2(\sqrt{6-x} + 2)(2\sqrt{3-x} + \sqrt{6-x})}|$

if $\delta < 1$, then $|\frac{3(2-x)}{2(\sqrt{6-x} + 2)(2\sqrt{3-x} + \sqrt{6-x})}| < \frac{3}{4}|x-2|$

Now choose, $\delta = \min\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{4\epsilon}{3}\}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Notice that using the conjugates,

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{6−x}−2}{\sqrt{3−x}−1}=\frac{2-x}{2-x}\dfrac{\sqrt{3−x}+1}{\sqrt{6−x}+2}$$ and the first fraction disappears.

The remaining one is continuous (the undeterminacy is gone) so that the limit is $f(2)=\dfrac12$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\sqrt{6-x}-2}{\sqrt{3-x}-1}$$

$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{2-x}{2-x}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3-x}+1}{\sqrt{6-x+2}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\sqrt{3-x}+1}{\sqrt{6-x+2}}$$

$$=\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$$